# How can I publish Word files to a WordPress blog without losing the footnotes?

Tags: html, editor, microsoft

I would like to take the contents from Microsoft Word files and convert them into WordPress blog posts without losing the footnotes. I've tried many different methods but have not found a simple working solution to this basic issue. The ideal solution would automatically upload a Word file (or many files) to a WordPress blog and convert the footnotes to HTML anchors.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your problem a bit better? Do you want to upload a wordfile to your media library and the footnotes of the .doc file were stripped out or do you want to upload a .doc file, extract the content and make a wordpress post out of it?

Comment: I don't think this works in stable, but Simple Footnotes (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-footnotes/) by Andrew Nacin has a feature in development to allow you to use paste from word and preserve the footnotes.

Comment: @John: Are you talking about [this extension to convert Word footnotes](http://ben.balter.com/2011/03/20/regular-expression-to-parse-word-style-footnotes/)? This looks interesting, why don't you copy it to an answer?

Comment: @Ari: If I copy text with footnotes from Word to the Visual editor, it copies the footnotes too. Does this also work for you? Is this enough? Have you tried [blogging directly from Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/help-with-blogging-in-word-HA010164021.aspx)?

Comment: When I upload a blog post from Word, it leaves out the footnotes entirely. When I paste in the word text, the footnotes are messed up (the links are to a specific location on my computer). I'll look at that regex link, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress Core does not support converting DOC files into posts. You might want to look at the range of importers that are available: [Importing Content (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content).

However the concept to import text into one blog post looks like a refreshing new concept to wordpress, core does not support anything at all of that.

Basically if you can convert something into a HTML fragment, you can just copy/paste that HTML over into the HTML editor of the post.

HTML has nothing like footnotes, so the conversion will lack of that feature and can only simulate footnotes then.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same thing. I found [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.org/docx-to-html) which seems to do a nice job of this (no affiliation to me). It's not a drop-in solution but it is something that could work. They have a [free tier of usage](https://cloudconvert.org/pricing) and reasonable prices beyond that.

You can also try just using the 'Save as HTML' from Word which gets pretty close.